# eloquent distinct select laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I want to show the company list with distinct is there's a way using eloquent? this code isn't working

```
public function create()
    {
      $goods = goods::all();
      $company = company::all()->distinct('name')->get();
      return view('pages.purchaseCreate',['goods' => $goods, 'company' =>$company]);
    }
```

this are the error message

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::distinct does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `all()` returns a collection. This should work:

```
$company = company::distinct('name')->get();
```